# siteground how to access remote database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two identical websites (site-A, site-B) hosting in Siteground under same hosting package. Two websites are set up and running and able to access 'localhost' database (site a link to DB-A, site B link to DB-B), all identical (website and database, except the DB name and user, password) !.

I want site-A to connect to DB-B, therefore, I do following :

1. In site-B: enter to site-A-ip (shown in dashboard of site-A) in the 'remote' under 'MySQL' under 'SITE'.
2. In site-A, edit my DB credential: 'localhost' change to 'site-B-ip', dbname to DB-B-name, dbuser to DB-B-user-name, dbpass to DB-B-user-pass.

Unable to get connected.

site-A config before the change :

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "*c2d9rouj***");
define("DB_NAME", "*bbsr9rcs4a***");
define("DB_PASS", "*ZK{.E*WJ***");
```

site-B config :

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "*p3gl3vjcz***");
define("DB_NAME", "*bsjseqnext***");
define("DB_PASS", "*ZK{.E*WJ***");
```

site-A config after change (try access DB-B):

```
define("DB_SERVER", "*5.213.***.**");
define("DB_USER", "*p3gl3vjcz***");
define("DB_NAME", "*bsjseqnext***");
define("DB_PASS", "*ZK{.E*WJ***");
```

Last, but important.  Siteground need developer provides feedback for the server or hosting end. What is that ? The chart is here : What I should feed back to them for support ?

```
Edward Wong: If I said, your DB is not able access remotely. Will this your scope of support ?

Todor G.: It most likely is not configured properly, but we would have to check it further of course, if your developer provides any feedback for the server or hosting end, we would be more than happy to review the reported issue and to have it resolved

Todor G.: As for now, it's best to check with a developer to address how the PHP website can be connected to a remote database

Todor G.: This is not something that we support, as it falls under the development end of the website

Todor G.: As I advised, we will be more than happy to look into this, after a developer's review

Todor G.: With this in mind, I wish you a nice rest of your day ahead

Todor G.: We are here for you 24/7 in case something comes up, bye bye for now
```

Comment: There seems to be an incomplete amount of information here. Is this a shared hosting or VPS setup? Is MySQL able to receive external connections? Is the user account configured for external access? Is there a firewall in the way?

Comment: If those are real credentials I suggest you change them as fast a possible

Comment: Thanks DarkBee, I had change some of the credential before publish.

Comment: "unable to get connected" isn't an error message. Tell us specifically what error you get please

Comment: Hi matigo, it is shared hosting, according siteground, it able to receive external connections (if I am not wrong), but the support does not say yes or not, just asks me to get developer feedback.  I do not know if there is any restrictions for external access, also siteground refused to answer.  I don't know if they have a firewall set, also siteground need developer feedback before checking.

Comment: Hi ADyson,  the error with my development environment (access from my PC) is as follows :(HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'up3gl3vjczfmo'@'n058152104108.netvigator.com' (using password: YES), it must a setting refused the connection, if I enter '%' (shown in dashboard of site-A) in the 'remote' under 'MySQL' under 'SITE'. It works.  But siteground ask for need developer provides feedback for the server or hosting end'.  I don't know how to deal with them.

Comment: Access Denied is reasonably good - it means it was able to connect at least, so there isn't a network issue. It probably just means you didn't configure the user account and host correctly in mysql - if it works with `%` as the host then that's good as well, but obviously for security you don't really want that all the time. Can you show the mysql user config? Also have you tried using the IP address of the connecting server as the host, rather than the domain name?

Comment: Hi ADyson,  Not password or typo.  it can connected and works fine if I change site-A-ip to %.  So the problem is site-A-ip, it is not the ip address shown the desshboard, but something else. But siteground need 'developer feed back' - where I can get is ?

Comment: You're getting it here, slowly. As requested please show the mysql user config. (You can change the IP address to a fake one, but it's important we can see the user setup info - host details and permissions.)

Comment: Hi ADyson,  Thanks, but the problem is siteground do not provide tools that can check the  mysql user config.  I can use phpMyAdmin, but not user or privieges can show.

Comment: Huh? You said you could change the privileges and credentials (e.g. changing to using %) so you must be able to view them as well, surely? Even if it's only via command line, or via running relevant scripts via PHP

Comment: Hi ADyson,  Siteground provide a tools to 'Add Remote Access Host'.  In the box, can put ip address, url, %.  similar to phpMyAdmin privileges 'host name' column. Can add or delete, not other function.

Comment: Ok I see. So maybe you need to a) show them exactly what you did and what error message you're getting, and explain that it works with %, and then b) ask them what the correct IP / hostname to use is if you want to use server A as a remote access host. If server A also belongs to siteground then they should be able to tell you the correct answer. In that chat, they said they would be able to look into it further if you could explain the configuration to them.

Comment: I haven't worked with siteground, but my experience of such hosting companies is that they're normally prepared to be very helpful, but you need to ask them a fairly specific question, so they understand that it falls into their area, and not just a "my application doesn't work" problem which they can't really get involved in solving.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, I basically know what is wrong, but the problem is they need 'developer feed back'. That is the problem.  Anyway.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Yes. but what they're really saying is that you need to give them specific details of the problem. You've got those details - as I just explained - but your chat conversation shows that you asked them an extremely vague question (which probably means they assumed you're not a developer and had no idea what you were doing).

Comment: Thanks Adyson,  the chart is very long, and I told them I had the same set up in other hosting company and ask them to check the configuration for me.  They support insist that I can access the 'localhost' sucessfully, the config is fine ...   and I definately told it is the remote access problem, they told me that is developer's scope, and ask for the 'developer's feedback'.  It make me very disappointed.

Comment: Yes they're right it's a remote access problem, and they're right that you probably configured it wrong. We've highlighted that you may have used the wrong IP address for the remote access IP. As I said before, you should explain the specific details to them, and  then ask for the correct IP address to use from server A. If it's their server, they should be able to tell you that information. I've told you this already, now you need to go and do it.

Comment: Hi ADyson,  the IP address is what they told me to set.  I check few times for typo mistake, and hope they can check for me.

Comment: Right well you didn't explain that before. I assumed you'd tried to figure it out yourself. But, from what you've shown, it doesn't look like you've done much wrong. So yes they need to check it, since it's all within their environment. Your PHP code is fine.

Comment: Hi ADyson,  Finally, after I showed this post as 'developer feedback' they check and provide a 'base ip address' to me, which is not shown in the dashboard, I add it use 'Add Remote Access Host' function. And everything works fine.  Thank you very much for your BIG BIG help on this matter !!!  Much appreciated !

Comment: No problem. glad it was resolved.